# How to delete up to a specific part of a line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I am trying to remove the specific text from the file. I have tried using `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*,/{/' beta.txt | head -n5
```

But didn't got the expected output.
Here is the input and output I got:

```
{"url":"example.com","original":"ex.com","tech":"c"}
{"url":"example1.com", jkdshsjkfhdj,"dsd":"sdsd","original":"ex1.com","tech":"d"}
```

The output I got is:

```
{"tech":"c"}
{"tech":"d"}
```

What I expect is:

```
{"original":"ex.com","tech":"c"}
{"original":"ex1.com","tech":"d"}
```

I just want to have `original` and everything before it should be replaced with `{`.

How I can achieve it?

Comment: Well, you can achieve it with `echo '{"original":"ex.com","tech":"c"}'` but that's probably not what you want ;). Please [edit] your question and explain what you are after. Do you want the last 2 comma-separated fields? Everything except the url (no matter how many fields you have)? Only lines matching `tech`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You weren't getting what you expected because regular expressions are greedy. Match anything but a comma `[^,]` instead of any character:

```
$ sed 's/[^,]*,/{/' beta.txt
{"original":"ex.com","tech":"c"}
{"original":"ex1.com","tech":"d"}
```

Since your edit though, apparently there's nothing consistent to match on all lines except `original` explicitly, so we'll have to do that... not much fun.

```
sed 's/.*,"original/{"original/'
```

Comment: is it possible if I do as `[^,"]` in your regex? I want that it should remove before ,"original

Comment: depends what you are trying to avoid matching @JafferWilson - like this? `sed 's/[^,]*,"/{"/'`

Comment: Yes, I am trying to have only original. Let me edit the question input

Comment: @JafferWilson since `,"` occurs before and after the field you want you'll have to match it explicitly - is that OK? `sed 's/.*,"original/{"original/'`

Answer (score 2):

Another one:

```
# sed 's/\".*com,//' sedtest
{"original":"ex.com","tech":"c"}
{"original":"ex1.com","tech":"d"}
```

**Edit:**
Use `-i` flag if you want to make changes to some file.
Like:

```
sed -i.bak 'regex_above' filename
```

Putting a dot on `-i` parameter creates a backup named **filename.bak** in the same dir as well.

Answer (score 1):

The proper question to ask here would be "How to keep only specific items in `json` dictionary" , because that's exactly what is seen in your examples.  Of course it is possible to do it via other text processing tools, but if we're working with `json`, then lets use proper tools for that.

Using python's `json` module, we can have the small script shown below, where you have list of items you want to keep. Assuming your input file is structured with one `json` dictionary per line, we can read the file line-by-line, and load each line as python's dictionary . From there it's straight road to victory - iterate over all the keys in the dictionary and see if they're on the list of items we want to keep; if they're not on that list - pop them out.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json,sys
keep = ['tech','original']
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        data=json.loads(line)
        for key in data.keys():
           if key not in keep: 
               data.pop(key)
        json.dump(data,sys.stdout)
        print ""
```

Test run:

```
$ cat input.json                                                                                      
{"url":"example.com","original":"ex.com","tech":"c"}
{"url":"example1.com","dsd":"sdsd","original":"ex1.com","tech":"d"}
$ ./remove_json_items.py input.json                                                                   
{"tech": "c", "original": "ex.com"}
{"tech": "d", "original": "ex1.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is search all the patern and repeat the part that you are interested in. with (....) you can use the content between ( ) and after, in the substitution field use \ and the number of content.

In this example I've made two text and the first \1 the second \2 so you are interested in \2 and your answer is:

```
sed 's/^{\(.*\),\(.*\),/{\2/' sedtest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also include the "original" tag:

```
's/{.*,"original"/{"original"/' beta.txt
```

Output:

```
{"original":"ex.com","tech":"c"}
{"original":"ex1.com","tech":"d"}
```